# how to access the data in the pie?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the data from the Pie but it is throwing error, I think it might be because I don't have a global variable that does that. If that's the issue, how can I do it?

```js
    if(cryptoCoin.length <= 4) {
      for(let i = 0; i < cryptoCoin.length; i++) {
        console.log('not more than 5 ' + cryptoCoin[i].name)

        const data = {
          labels: cryptoCoin[i].name,
          datasets: [{
            data: [cryptoCoin[i].dollarAmount],
          }]
        }

      }
    } else if (cryptoCoin.length >= 5) {
      for(let i = 0; i < cryptoCoin.length; i++) {
        console.log('more than 5 ' + cryptoCoin[i].name)
      }
    }

return(
    <Pie data={data} />
)
```

Comment: What error?? [Edit] to quote it in full.

Comment: You can not have access to the data variable outside of the if statement, because it is a marked as a const, and in javascript const and let are blocked scope (meaning only accessible in the scope of their declaration and it's child scopes

Answer (score 0):

the data is not defined because it is in the local scope. You should take out the data object from the if statement

```
const data  = {};  
if(cryptoCoin.length <= 4) {
      for(let i = 0; i < cryptoCoin.length; i++) {
        console.log('not more than 5 ' + cryptoCoin[i].name)

        data = {
          labels: cryptoCoin[i].name,
          datasets: [{
            data: [cryptoCoin[i].dollarAmount],
          }]
        }

      }
    } else if (cryptoCoin.length >= 5) {
      for(let i = 0; i < cryptoCoin.length; i++) {
        console.log('more than 5 ' + cryptoCoin[i].name)
      }
    }

return(
    <Pie data={data} />
)
```

Comment: This solution would not work, You have declared data as a constant

Comment: and how can i send the data from inside the loop to the data outside?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have access to the data variable outside of the if statement, because it is a marked as a `const`, and in javascript `const` and `let` are blocked scope (meaning only accessible in the scope of their declaration and it's child scopes.

**Solution**

```
const someFunction = () => {
 let data  = {};  
   if(cryptoCoin.length <= 4) {
      for(let i = 0; i < cryptoCoin.length; i++) {
        console.log('not more than 5 ' + cryptoCoin[i].name)

        data = {
          labels: cryptoCoin[i].name,
          datasets: [{
            data: [cryptoCoin[i].dollarAmount],
          }]
        }

      }
    } else if (cryptoCoin.length >= 5) {
      for(let i = 0; i < cryptoCoin.length; i++) {
        console.log('more than 5 ' + cryptoCoin[i].name)
      }
    }

    return(
      <Pie data={data} />
    )
}
```

Comment: how do I send the data from inside the loop to the outside?